# Coding for loop with an assembler in c++ function

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I was always interested in assembler, however so far I didn't have a true chance to confront it in a best way. Now, when I do have some time, I began coding some small programs using assembler in a c++, but that's just small ones, i.e. define x, store it somewhere and so on, so forth. I wanted to implement foor loop in assembler, but I couldn't make it, so I would like to ask if anyone here has ever done with it, would be nice to share here. Example of some function would be

`for(i=0;i<10;i++) { std::cout<< "A"; }`

Anyone has some idea how to implement this in a assembler?

edit2: ISA x86

Comment: I think the implementation of std::cout by itself would be a giant task in assembly.

Comment: You can always write code in C++, look at the generated assembly code and get hints on how to do it yourself.

Comment: What assembly language? Also sometimes you can use a syscall in assembly to very simply print something to stdout (I know MIPS does, not sure about x86)

Comment: @ssg And make sure to disable optimizations!

Comment: I think it might be easier to call `printf` than to try to use `cout::operator<<`

Comment: @ssg: A call to `std::cout`'s `<<` operator compiles to a call to `__ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc`. It's ugly as hell, and not a good way to learn assembly. :)

Comment: @duskwuff what compiler? GCC4.7 uses a single underscore at the start.

Comment: It's x86 @SethCarnegie. Ethan Steinberg Yes, I do know that it would require giant task to process, however it wasn't my question of focus. I wanted to see if there is however some solution( i bet there must exist some) in assembly that would simulate the behavior of the c++ foor loop.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Putchar would be even easier to use.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually looking at both (optimizations on and off) is also a good exercise :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the unoptimized output<sup>1</sup> of GCC for this code:

```
void some_function(void);

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 137; ++i) { some_function(); }
}
```

```
    movl    $0, 12(%esp)            // i = 0; i is stored at %esp + 12
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    call    some_function           // some_function()
    addl    $1, 12(%esp)            // ++i
.L2:
    cmpl    $136, 12(%esp)          // compare i to 136 ...
    jle .L3                         //   ... and repeat loop less-or-equal

    movl    $0, %eax                // return 0
    leave                           //  --"--
```

With optimization `-O3`, the addition+comparison is turned into subtraction:

```
    pushl   %ebx          // save %ebx
    movl    $137, %ebx    // set %ebx to 137

    // some unrelated parts

.L2:
    call    some_function // some_function()
    subl    $1, %ebx      // subtract 1 from %ebx
    jne .L2               // if not equal to 0, repeat loop
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>The generated assembly can be examined by invoking GCC with the `-S` flag.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Try to rewrite the `for` loop in C++ using a `goto` and an `if` statement and you will have the basics for the assembly version.

Comment: And using `printf` or `puts` instead of iostreams. That'll make it a lot easier to understand...

Comment: I assume what he wants to know is the `for` loop because of course for the `cout` it is another story ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the reverse - write the program in C++ or C and look at the dissasembled code:

```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
00E714EE  mov         dword ptr [i],0 
00E714F5  jmp         wmain+30h (0E71500h) 
00E714F7  mov         eax,dword ptr [i] 
00E714FA  add         eax,1 
00E714FD  mov         dword ptr [i],eax 
00E71500  cmp         dword ptr [i],0Ah 
00E71504  jge         wmain+4Bh (0E7151Bh) 
        cout << "A";
00E71506  push        offset string "A" (0E76800h) 
00E7150B  mov         eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (0E792ECh)] 
00E71510  push        eax  
00E71511  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (0E71159h) 
00E71516  add         esp,8 
00E71519  jmp         wmain+27h (0E714F7h)
```

then try to make sense of it.